# Envers can't find audit tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway, hibernate-envers

I want to use Envers in my project. The hardest part is to create audit tables. The database structure is created by flyway migrations. Therefore `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`. According to the documentation I should use `org.hibernate.envers.tools.hbm2ddl.EnversSchemaGenerator` to create schema programmatically. But I didn't find any examples how to do it.

I created flyway migrations for audit tables. However seems like envers can't find them during the start for dev conf. Test conf works just fine. Here is my application.yml for dev:

```
spring.datasource:
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/server?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8
username: root
spring.jpa:
database: MYSQL
show-sql: true
hibernate:
    ddl-auto: validate
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
properties.org.hibernate.envers:
    default_schema: server_audit
    audit_table_suffix: _history
```

and Test:

```
spring:
profiles: test
spring.datasource:
driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS \"public\"\;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS \"SERVER_AUDIT\"
spring.jpa:
database: H2
show-sql: true
hibernate:
    ddl-auto: validate
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

During the start there is an exception:

```
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData   : HHH000262: Table not found: accounts_history

[lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: accounts_history
```

Then I changed `hbm2ddl.auto = update` the output is weird:

```
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData  : HHH000262: Table not found: accounts_history
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table server_audit.accounts_history
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : Table 'accounts_history' already exists
```

and it starts.

**UPDATE**
Can anyone provide example how to create audit tables using

```
org.hibernate.envers.tools.hbm2ddl.EnversSchemaGenerator
```

?